# Consulta SQL con datos String

Tags: java, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, jdbc

Hola tengo una consulta `SQL` implementada en **JAVA** en la cual necesito insertar los valores MTILM, MVisual,MVerba,MAR,MTeorico cuyos datos son de tipo String, acá les dejo un ejemplo

```
connectionDB.executeInsertUpdate("INSERT INTO `data_processed`(`id`, `ti_log_mat`, `ea_visual`, `ea_verbal`, `ea_act_ref`, `ea_teorico`, `class`) VALUES(" + cond1.getInt(1) + ",'" + MTILM + "','" + MVisual + "','" + MVerbal + "','" + MAR + "','" + MTeorico + "',0);");
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente Error:

> at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:1198)
>   at
>   fase1_clasificacion.ConnectionDB.executeInsertUpdate(ConnectionDB.java:65)
>   at
>   fase1_clasificacion.DataProcessed.QuizPrePro(DataProcessed.java:270)
>   at fase1_clasificacion.DataProcessed.main(DataProcessed.java:46) at
>   fase1_clasificacion.Face1_Clasificacion.main(Face1_Clasificacion.java:30)

Debido a que algo hay mal supongo que en la concatenacón de los datos, podría alguien decirme ¿Qué tengo mal implementado?

Comment: como queda el string de ejecucion del query una vez que concatenaste todo?

Answer (score 2):

Siempre use una `PreparedStatement` para construir consultas, ya que se encarga de automatizar escape.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("INSERT INTO `data_processed`");
    sb.append("(`id`, `ti_log_mat`, `ea_visual`, `ea_verbal`, `ea_act_ref`, `ea_teorico`, `class`)"); 
    sb.append(" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conexionBD.prepareStatement(sb.toString);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1,cond1.getInt(1));
    preparedStatement.setString(2, MTILM);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, MVisual);
    preparedStatement.setString(4, MVerbal);
    preparedStatement.setString(5, MAR);
    preparedStatement.setString(6, MTeorico);
    preparedStatement.setInt(7, 0); 

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

También para concatenar en java es mejor hacerlo con `stringbuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

Se recomienda usar **consultas preparadas** para hacer operaciones del tipo CRUD en la Base de Datos. Ver en ese sentido la [documentación de Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

En las consultas preparadas se pasan por separado la cadena SQL y los datos, representados en la cadena por el signo de `?`. De esa manera se evita la Inyección SQL de primer grado.

En cada una de las líneas de `preparedStatement...`, por ejemplo:

`preparedStatement.setInt(1,cond1.getInt(1));`

se pasan los datos que se quieren insertar, indicando el tipo (`setInt, setString`), la posición (`1, 2...`) teniendo en cuenta que cada dato debe corresponder con lo que indicas más arriba en el `INSERT INTO ...` y por último el valor que quieres insertar (`cond1.getInt(1), MTILM ...`).

**Debe haber tantos signos de `?` como columnas en la parte izquierda del `INSERT INTO ...` e igual número de llamadas al método `preparedStatement.set ...`**

Ejemplo:

```
String sSQL=
            "INSERT INTO `data_processed`"
            + " (`id`, `ti_log_mat`, `ea_visual`, `ea_verbal`, `ea_act_ref`, `ea_teorico`, `class`)" 
            + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connectionDB.prepareStatement(sSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1,cond1.getInt(1));
preparedStatement.setString(2, MTILM);
preparedStatement.setString(3, MVisual);
preparedStatement.setString(4, MVerbal);
preparedStatement.setString(5, MAR);
preparedStatement.setString(6, MTeorico);
preparedStatement.setInt(7, 0); 

// ejecutar
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Nota: Se necesitan algunos import. [Aquí puedes ver](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) un ejemplo completo.

Comment: +1 Donde dice "Se recomienda" debería decir "Se recomienda fuertemente" :-) De veras, eso de armar consultas SQL dinámicas pegando strings es pésima práctica.

Answer (score 1):

El query que muestras esta bien formulado, pero mi recomendación es que utilices el PreparedStatement, le dará mas seguridad a tu consulta y debugeando podrás ver exactamente el error, lo de seguridad lo digo porque evita las inyecciones de sql, entre otras cosas.
Espero te sirva.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Por cierto deberías copiar la función tal cual porque como esta estructurada parece que la volviste a escribir qui y quizá no vemos el error por eso.